# is there a better way to retrieve datetime object from list?

Tags: python, datetime

Edit: Updated code example here, https://repl.it/@HexKiz/FussyQuietPetabyte

```
import datetime
```

## from datetime import datetime

emp_history = {
    1: ['Vox', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 2, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 2, 0, 1), 1.0],
    2: ['telly', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 2, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 2, 0, 1), 1.0]
}

def print_all(dict_emp_history):
    # Sort keys from 1 -> last and print all records
    for x in sorted(dict_emp_history.keys()):

```
    # Get Tuple Values
    name = ([x[0] for x in dict_emp_history.values()])
    start = ([x[1] for x in dict_emp_history.values()])
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(start), '%Y%M%d')

    end = ([x[2] for x in dict_emp_history.values()])
    total = ([x[3] for x in dict_emp_history.values()])
    print('---------------')
    print('This is record: {}'.format(x))
    print(dict_emp_history[x])
    print('{}   -Start:   {}  -End:   {}  -Total:   {}'.format(name, start, end, total))
    print('---------------')
```

def main():
    print_all(emp_history)

main()

---

Noticed that retrieving a value from a list returns it as a list item.
The value in question is datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 8, 0, 9) a datetime object.

What I need to do is, is retrieve the datetime object and print it as a string, so that it looks like something like this 2018.01.20. I know you can use strftime, but I keep getting errors thrown that the value is not a datetime object.

Does this mean I have to convert the list to a string, then back to a datetime object?

Surely there must be a better way to do this.

---

```
import datetime


td = {
    1: ('hex', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 8, 0, 9), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), 0.9999923896499239),
    2: ('hex', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 8, 0, 9), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), 0.9999923896499239)
}

print(td)

value = ([x[2] for x in td.values()])



print(value)
print(type(value))
```

---

```
{1: ('hex', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 8, 0, 9), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), 0.9999923896499239), 2: ('hex', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 8, 0, 9), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), 0.9999923896499239)}
[datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5)]
<class 'list'>
```

I expected the type for the var named value to be of type datetime object.

Comment: `I expected the type for the var named value to be of type datetime object.` Why? It's a *list* of datetimes. Also, can you show your attempts with `strftime`?

Comment: @Tomothy32 shown here: https://repl.it/@HexKiz/FussyQuietPetabyte

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result of the list comprehension to *value*. As Tomothy32 pointed out in his comment, *value* is a list of datetime objects.

As for retrieving a datetime object from the list and printing it as a string, the following code should do what you expect:

```
value = ([str(x[2]) for x in td.values()])
```

The output of the above is:

```
['2002-01-08 00:05:00', '2002-01-08 00:05:00']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the output for that on my screen is: 

[datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 0, 5)] of type list.

i could use str() to force it to be a string, but the string library cannot convert this to a datetime object. 

I could hack this and shop the string apart, but that doesnt seem to be an ideal solution